# How do ki foci work?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, implements

I have a few questions since I don't fully understand ki foci.

1. If I have, say, an accurate superior ki focus, can you enchant it to
   be a +1 magic accurate ki focus (+2 to attack rolls and +1 to damage
   rolls) like how magic weapons keep damage dice and properties like
   reach, etc.?
2. If an executioner uses a +1 magic ki focus with a weapon that has +3
   proficiency (say, a dagger) would it be +4 to attack rolls or would
   it be a choice between the dagger proficiency and the +1 ki focus?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE!  Please take the [tour] and take a look at the [help] to get a feel for how this Q&A site works.  Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, superior ki foci can be enchanted.**

As with other superior implements, superior ki foci are still ki focus implements and can be enchanted just like a non-superior ki focus. Superior implements are basically an implement-user's equivalent of exotic weapons: you spend a feat to be able to use a version of your preferred implement/weapon that has some additional bonuses.

**Ki foci can apply their *enchantment* benefits to weapon attacks.**

When a character who is proficient with ki foci makes a weapon attack, they can choose to use the *enchantment* on their ki focus *instead of* the enchantment on their weapon. It's still a weapon attack, so it still gets the proficiency bonus. You *cannot* apply the bonuses from a *superior* ki focus to a weapon attack, however.

As an example, let's say an executioner has a +2 flaming dagger and a +5 magic accurate ki focus. When she attacks with the dagger, she always gets the dagger's +3 proficiency bonus on the attack roll. She can then choose to receive the dagger's +2 enhancement bonus on the attack roll *or* the ki focus' +5 enhancement bonus, but not both. If she chooses the ki focus' +5 enhancement bonus, she *cannot* also make use of the dagger's flaming enchantment to turn its damage into fire damage. She *never* gets the +1 attack bonus from the ki focus being an accurate superior ki focus (when making weapon attacks; it would apply to all implement attacks).

Basically, when you have an enchanted ki focus and an enchanted weapon and make a weapon attack, you can choose to use the ki focus' enchantment *instead of* the enchantment on the weapon. This choice only affects the bonuses from magical enchantments; other bonuses, such as the weapon proficiency bonus on the attack roll, are not affected.

Answer (score 3):

1: Ki focuses being an Implement, they can be enchanted in the same way as any other implement or weapon.

2: Yes, you would choose whether to use the enhancement value of the dagger or the Ki focus.

Do keep in mind, however page 64 of PHB 3:

> If you have both a magic ki focus and a magic weapon, you choose before
>   you use an attack power whether to draw on the magic of the ki focus or
>   the weapon. Your choice determines which enhancement bonus, critical
>   hit effects, and magic item properties and powers you can apply to
>   that power.

So when attacking with a +2 bloodthirsty Maul and a +3 Accurate Ki Focus, you essentially choose between using a +2 Bloodthirsty Maul or a +3 Maul. (Losing the Accurate tag, because that's a property of the Focus and thus not applied to the weapon it's being used with)
Weapon properties remain the same.

Comment: You are indeed correct! I shall correct that.

Comment: +1 for the "choose between a +2 Bloodthirsty Maul and a +3 Maul", that's a good way to think of it.